# Creating an instance of a class in Java?

Tags: java, class

In Java, I am trying to create an instance of a class that gets passed as a parameter. For instance:

```
public Class<? extends superclass> theClass;

public constructor(Class<? extends superclass> myClass){
    this.theClass = myClass;
}

public superclass getInstance(){
    return < AN INSTANCE OF theClass >
}
```

I do not know how I would create an instance of `theClass`...
Is this possible, or will I need to find another way of doing it?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the factory design pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
return this.theClass.newInstance();
```

More in [`java.lang.Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) and [`java.lang.reflect`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html), including a way to find other constructors that the class may have and a means of calling them with arguments.

For instance, suppose you know you need to call a constructor that accepts a `String` argument. You can use [`getConstructor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-) to locate that constructor:

```
Constructor ctor = this.theClass.getConstructor(String.class);
```

...and then call it

```
return ctor.newInstance("the string");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call [`Class#newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()):

```
public Superclass getInstance() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return theClass.newInstance();
}
```

From the Javadocs:

> Creates a new instance of the class represented by this `Class` object. The class is instantiated as if by a `new` expression with an empty argument list. The class is initialized if it has not already been initialized.

Comment: Just what I needed! Thanks for including the Javadocs info too!